# AttributeError when using pandas and Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pandas, flask, attributeerror

I understand that Pandas isn't included and believe that I've properly included the library via adding the module into the lib directory for the app and by adding

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
vendor.add('lib')
```

to **appengine_config.py** - other modules don't seem to be having issues.

When I run my app, the following stack trace shows up:

> ERROR    2016-12-15 23:05:31,038 app.py:1587] Exception on / [GET]
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File
>   ".../PycharmProjects/fpl-flask-app/lib/flask/app.py", line 1988, in
>   wsgi_app
>   response = self.full_dispatch_request()
>    File
>   ".../PycharmProjects/fpl-flask-app/lib/flask/app.py", line 1641, in
>   full_dispatch_request
>         rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
>    File ".../PycharmProjects/fpl-flask-app/lib/flask/app.py", line 1544, in
>   handle_user_exception
>         reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>    File ".../PycharmProjects/fpl-flask-app/lib/flask/app.py", line 1639, in
>   full_dispatch_request
>         rv = self.dispatch_request()
>    File ".../PycharmProjects/fpl-flask-app/lib/flask/app.py", line 1625, in
>   dispatch_request
>         return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint
>    File ".../PycharmProjects/fpl-flask-app/main.py", line 13, in index
>       
>   datar = pandas.read_sql('SELECT p.nationality, SUM(s.mins_played) AS mins_played 
>   FROM CurrentSeasonStats s left join Player p ON
>   s.Player_pid = p.pid GROUP BY 
>   p.nationality', con)
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'read_sql'**

Here's my code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import pandas
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pymysql

import random

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    con = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://user:pass@ix.cs.uoregon.edu:port/fpl', echo=False)
    datar = pandas.read_sql('SELECT p.nationality, SUM(s.mins_played) AS mins_played FROM CurrentSeasonStats s left join Player p ON s.Player_pid = p.pid GROUP BY p.nationality', con)
    return render_template('index.html', table=datar)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had copy-pasted a Binary Skeleton version of the pandas library into /lib/ which is why none of the pandas functions were working.

This a direct and annoying result of me not using virtual environments...

USE VIRTUAL ENVIRONMENTS, KIDS!